# Importing, reading from csv file and display it into table view for javafx

Tags: java, csv, javafx, tableview

I've been stuck in this error for quite sometimes, can anyone point out to me on solving this error?

```
package loadCSV;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CSVTable extends Application {

    public class Record {
        //Assume each record have 6 elements, all String

        private SimpleStringProperty f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;

        public String getF1() {
            return f1.get();
        }


        public String getF2() {
            return f2.get();
        }

        public String getF3() {
            return f3.get();
        }

        public String getF4() {
            return f4.get();
        }

        public String getF5() {
            return f5.get();
        }

        public String getF6() {
            return f6.get();
        }


        Record(String f1,String f2, String f3, String f4, String f5, String f6) {
            this.f1 = new SimpleStringProperty(f1);
            this.f2 = new SimpleStringProperty(f2);
            this.f3 = new SimpleStringProperty(f3);
            this.f4 = new SimpleStringProperty(f4);
            this.f5 = new SimpleStringProperty(f5);
            this.f6 = new SimpleStringProperty(f6);
        }

    }

    private final TableView<Record> tableView = new TableView<>();

    private final ObservableList<Record> dataList
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("CSV");

        Group root = new Group();

        TableColumn columnF1 = new TableColumn("f1");
        columnF1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f1"));

        TableColumn columnF2 = new TableColumn("f2");
        columnF2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f2"));

        TableColumn columnF3 = new TableColumn("f3");
        columnF3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f3"));

        TableColumn columnF4 = new TableColumn("f4");
        columnF4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f4"));

        TableColumn columnF5 = new TableColumn("f5");
        columnF5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f5"));

        TableColumn columnF6 = new TableColumn("f6");
        columnF6.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("f6"));

        tableView.setItems(dataList);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(columnF1, columnF2, columnF3, columnF4, columnF5, columnF6);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(100);
        vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        //run in background thread
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                readCSV();
            };

        }.start(); 
       /* readCSV();*/


    }


    private void readCSV(){
        String file = "test.csv";
        String fieldDelimiter = ",(?=([^\"]\"[^\"]\")[^\"]$)";

        BufferedReader br;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    String[] fields = line.split(fieldDelimiter, -1);
                    Record record = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2],
                            fields[3], fields[4], fields[5]); 
                    System.out.println(fields[2]);
                    dataList.add(record);


                    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

And the error I got is...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
                   at loadCSV.CSVTable.readCSV(CSVTable.java:138)
                   at loadCSV.CSVTable.access$0(CSVTable.java:127)
                   at loadCSV.CSVTable$1.run(CSVTable.java:117)
```

hope that someone could help! I've referenced http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2016/06/read-csv-file-display-in-javafx.html but the codes still don't work

Comment: You code formatting is off, try using a code formatter like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm. Also, please include a sample of the csv you are trying to load.

Comment: @RickSuggs hi there, the dataset I've taken from is from [link](https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment)

Comment: The link takes me to a site that requires me to create an account to access the csv. That's too much. You can remove all but the first two lines of your csv and see if the error still occurs. If so, share those two lines here.

Comment: tweet_created || retweet || airline_sentiment
24/2/15 11:35         13            positive 
24/2/15 11:15           2            positive

Comment: @RickSuggs issit okay u drop your email here and i send you the csv file? it is very hard to share here..

Comment: You should share the file in the original question.. with the code that you pasted. It gives people more context to solve the problem.

Comment: Next, you should research what a csv file is. What are the important characteristics of a csv file, and how do they differ from your file. The error is occurring on line 138 of your script. You can tell from the error message: `at loadCSV.CSVTable.readCSV(CSVTable.java:138)` Think of what is happening on that line and what could go wrong.

Comment: Apart from the exception you're getting (which is caused by the CSV file not being formatted in the way you're assuming, as already pointed out), you should not change the data in the table in a background thread. You need your `readCSV` file to return a new list, and then once that's complete, use `Platform.runLater(...)` to set that list as the table's items list.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception ? Please mark it with a comment